# JavaScript click event handler not fired in the code below

Tags: reactjs

I have the following `const` to set the dialog box content. The dialog box opened, the buttons associated with `yesButtonOnClick` and `noButtonOnClick` never fired.

```
const [openDialog, setDialog] = useState(false);
const [actionDetails, setActionDetails] = useState({});

const handleCloseDialog = () => {
    return setDialog(false);
};

const handleCancelEvent = () => {
    console.log('cancel event');

    //make a call to the server to cancel this events

    //close modal after done
    return setDialog(false);
};

const modalTypes = {
    'cancel-event': {
        noButtonOnClick: handleCloseDialog,
        noButtonOnClickBody: 'No, Don&rsquo;t Cancel',
        yesButtonOnClick: handleCancelEvent,
        yesButtonOnClickBody: 'Yes, Cancel Please.',
        dialogTitleId: 'cancel-event-dialog-title',
        dialogContentTextId: 'cancel-event-dialog-description',
        dialogContentTextIdBody:
            'Cancelling the event will notify all your students and tickets will be refunded.',
        ariaLabelledBy: 'cancel-event-dialog-title',
        ariaDescribedBy: 'cancel-event-dialog-description',
    },
}

const handleOpenDialog = (action_type) => {
    console.log('open cancel dialog', modalTypes[action_type]);
    handleClosePopover();
    setActionDetails(action_type);
    return setDialog(true);
};

<Dialog
            open={openDialog}
            onClose={handleCloseDialog}
            aria-labelledby='cancel-event-dialog-title'
            aria-describedby='cancel-event-dialog-description'
        >
            <DialogTitle id='cancel-event-dialog-title'>
                {'Are you sure you want to CANCEL?'}
            </DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <DialogContentText id='cancel-event-dialog-description'>
                    Cancelling the event will notify all your students and tickets will be refunded.
                    <TextareaAutosize
                        aria-label='cancel event message to attendees'
                        placeholder='Write a message to your attendees, with reason for cancellation.'
                        rowsMin={5}
                        rowsMax={10}
                        className={classes.textarea}
                    />
                </DialogContentText>
            </DialogContent>
            <DialogActions>
                <Button
                    onClick={actionDetails.yesButtonOnClick}
                    color='primary'
                    variant='outlined'
                    autoFocus
                >
                    Yes, Cancel Please.
                </Button>
                <Button onClick={actionDetails.noButtonOnClick} color='primary' variant='contained'>
                    No, Don&rsquo;t Cancel
                </Button>
            </DialogActions>
```

[image: my console when dialog is first triggered, so action_type is correctly set]

Comment: if can display sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) .it's great.

Comment: What is `actionDetails`? and where does it come from?

Comment: @DBS it's just a hook that sets it to modalTypes['event_type'] when the button click gets fired (w/handleOpenDialog)

Comment: needs debugging details.

Comment: @Leonardo I posted console info. it seems like function was never executed.

Comment: I found the bug, it was quite stupid. I set it the hook incorrectly as `setActionDetails(action_type);`, where it should've been `setActionDetails(modalTypes[action_type]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't show us the crucial part and that is the invocation of your `handleOpenDialog` function. In the example of your `console.log` within that function, you're accessing the data using `modalTypes[action_type]` which makes me think you're passing `action_type` itself as a string to your function. You're then setting `action_type` string as a value of `actionDetails` which seems plain wrong because you're later on trying to access the `actionDetails` functions from your `Dialog` component. What you should do instead is to set the `actionDetails` to the value you logged, which is `modalTypes[action_type]`. If I assumed everything correctly, it should fix your problem. I've also created [an example](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-r7kzi?file=/demo.js) to demonstrate you the functionality.

**Summary:**

```
const handleOpenDialog = (action_type) => {
    console.log('open cancel dialog', modalTypes[action_type]);
    handleClosePopover();
    setActionDetails(modalTypes[action_type]); // <-- Changed it from action_type
    return setDialog(true);
};
```

Comment: yes, I found that was the case...very dummy mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong you don't need to do return with the set

```
return setDialog(true);
```

Instead just do

```
setDialog(true);
```